# Nginx. React. Vite. Get dev version of my react app with nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I want access my vite's react app at localhost:80 with nginx's reverse-proxy

Im launching `dev` and `preview` versions of my react app at `5173` and `4173` ports.

I can easily get them with my browser at corresponding ports at `localhost:5173` and `localhost:4173`

[image]

*Here you can see `dev` version of app. It is not bundled, it is accessable without nginx*

[image]

*Here you can see `preview` version of app. It **`IS`** bundled, it is accessable without nginx*

Then Im launching **`nginx`** with following .conf at **`80 port`**

```
worker_processes  1;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  *.sserverless.ru sserverless.ru;

        charset utf-16;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4173;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }

        location /dev {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5173;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
}
```

Im ok with `location /`, Im getting builded-bundled version of my app **with** nginx:

[image]

*Here you can see, that sources are already bundled*

But when Im trying to achive `dev` version of my react app with nginx, Im getting this:

[image]

Here NOT translatable Chineese text from screenshot (Or, I guess, it is not translatable):

ℼ潤瑣灹⁥瑨汭ਾ格浴⁬慬杮∽湥㸢ਊ格慥㹤 㰠捳楲瑰琠灹㵥洢摯汵≥椾灭牯⁴⁻湩敪瑣湉潴汇扯污潈歯素映潲⁭⼢牀慥瑣爭晥敲桳㬢椊橮捥䥴瑮䝯潬慢䡬潯⡫楷摮睯㬩眊湩潤⹷判晥敲桳敒⑧㴠⠠ 㸽笠㭽眊湩潤⹷判晥敲桳楓⑧㴠⠠ 㸽⠠祴数 㸽琠灹㭥⼼捳楲瑰ਾ 㰠捳楲瑰琠灹㵥洢摯汵≥猠捲∽䀯楶整振楬湥≴㰾猯牣灩㹴ਊ†洼瑥⁡档牡敳㵴唢䙔㠭•㸯 㰠楬歮爠汥∽捩湯•祴数∽浩条⽥癳⭧浸≬栠敲㵦⼢楶整献杶•㸯 㰠敭慴渠浡㵥瘢敩灷牯≴挠湯整瑮∽楷瑤㵨敤楶散眭摩桴‬湩瑩慩⵬捳污㵥⸱∰⼠ਾ†琼瑩敬匾牥敶汲獥㱳琯瑩敬ਾ⼼敨摡ਾ㰊潢祤ਾ†搼癩椠㵤爢潯≴㰾搯癩ਾ†猼牣灩⁴祴数∽潭畤敬•牳㵣⼢牳⽣灡⽰湩敤⹸獴≸㰾猯牣灩㹴㰊戯摯㹹ਊ⼼瑨汭

I also don't know where this text comes from.

## Question:

What Im doing wrong? Or how get `dev` version of my app accessable at `5173` port with `nginx`?